# App Flutter funciona no Emulador do Android Studio mas não no celular

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, google-sheets

Todo o projeto, inclusive o back-end funciona perfeitamente quando executado no emulador do Android no Android Studio, mas quando gero o arquivo APK em modo release e executo no meu smartphone, somente o front-end funciona, já o back-end não funciona.

Estou clonando o projeto https://github.com/PatilShreyas/Flutter2GoogleSheets-Demo e obtenho o resultado negativo. Mesmo seguindo as orientações do site https://itnext.io/dart-working-with-google-sheets-793ed322daa0, também tenho o mesmo resultado. Funciona no PC mas quando gero o APK e instalo no celular não funciona, mesmo utilizando os mesmos códigos.

Já tentei o comando $flutter doctor e não aparece nenhum erro!

Tentei utilizar versões diferentes do Android para debugar sem sucesso!

Creio que possa ser uma configuração no Android Studio que está passando desapercebido.

Eu sinceramente não sei onde está o problema, agradeço caso alguém possa me apontar possíveis soluções.

Answer (score -1):

Consegui Resolver com base nas orientações encontradas em https://codeshare.io/5M6nA3.

Entretanto tive dificuldade para encontrar onde era necessário fazer a alteração:

É preciso abrir o arquivo:
..\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
que está nas pasta do seu projeto

e acrescentar a permissão:

> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

na segunda linha. logo após o <manifest ....>

Espero ter ajudado outros que tenham tido o mesmo problema!!